# emberjs checkedBinding on Em.Checkbox doesn't work

Tags: ember.js

Why doesn't this checkedBinding on an Em.Checkbox work?

Here is a code snippet illustrating the problem:

With this template

```
{{#each person in people}}
      <li>{{view Em.Checkbox checkedBinding=person.isSelected}}</li>
  {{/each}}
```

and this controller

```
App.IndexController = Em.Controller.extend({
    count: function(){
        return this.get('people').filterBy('isSelected').get('length');
    }.property('people.@each.isSelected'),
    people: Em.A([
          Person.create({firstName: 'Kris', lastName: 'Selden', isSelected: true}),
          Person.create({firstName: 'Luke', lastName: 'Melia', isSelected: false}),
          Person.create({firstName: 'Formerly Alex', lastName: 'Matchneer', isSelected: false})
      ])
});
```

I see all the check boxes unchecked

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7YkvB/2/) is a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to wrap your `checkedBinding` in quotation marks, like so:

```
{{#each person in people}}
   <li>{{view Em.Checkbox checkedBinding="person.isSelected"}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

See [this working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7YkvB/3/)